# How to cast Generic Lists dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, list, casting

I'm trying to cast `List<object>` to `List<string>` dynamically. I've tried several ways, but I can't find a solution. This is a small sample that shows the problem:

```
List<object> listObject = new List<object>();
listObject.Add("ITEM 1");
listObject.Add("ITEM 2");
listObject.Add("ITEM 3");

List<string> listString = ¿¿listObject??;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This won't be possible in version 4 either, because it is not typesafe to either "upcast" or "downcast" a `List<T>` - it's invariant, not covariant or contravariant. By the way, I'm getting tired of this misinformation being posted to every question about collection co/contravariance.

Answer (score 18):

If you can use LINQ then the [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method will do what you need:

```
List<string> listString = listObject.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

You can also use the [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) method, as Stan points out in his answer:

```
List<string> listString = listObject.ConvertAll(x => (string)x);
```

If you're not using C#3 then you'll need to use the "old" delegate syntax rather than a lambda:

```
List<string> listString =
    listObject.ConvertAll(delegate(object x) { return (string)x; });
```

Comment: @nader: I always try to remember that when LINQ isn't available then neither is lambda syntax.

Comment: And just to pre-empt any nitpickers... I'm aware that VS2008 can target earlier versions of the .NET framework, which would allow the use of lambda syntax but not LINQ. But, as a rule-of-thumb, no LINQ usually means no lambdas too.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .NET 3.5 you can use, this way you don't have to do an extra ToList(). You can also supply your own converter if you need to convert advanced objects.

```
 List<string> listString = listObject.ConvertAll(x=> x as String);
```

If you can't use LINQ you can do this

```
foreach(object item in listObject)
{
  string convertedItem = item as String;
  if(convertedItem != null)
       listString.Add(convertedItem);
}
```

Comment: This is also supported in .NET 2.0 (without LINQ, though the delgate syntax is not as nice). One note though, I don't believe the .Cast<string>.ToList() will create an "extra" list as you're implying. It will create one new list, for the result, as does your approach

Comment: I think you mean C# 3.0 and .Net 3.5.

Comment: @nader: I was implying that ToList() does an extra enumeration.

Comment: @Stan: Are you sure? ToList() will cause an enumeration, but that's it.  Cast<string>() will not actually enumerate the collection.

Comment: @Nader: I am pretty sure Cast enumerates it once to perform the cast on each object and then ToList does another enumeration I believe (it calls CopyTo)

Comment: @Stan: The `Cast` method just returns an iterator object which does nothing until you actually start enumerating the sequence (with `ToList`, `foreach` etc), at which point it casts and streams one element at a time. The sequence is only enumerated once.

Comment: @Stan: Having said that, although both the "`Cast` then `ToList`" approach and the `ConvertAll` approach only enumerate the sequence once, I'd expect `ConvertAll` to be marginally quicker because it loops through the source `List`'s underlying array directly rather than using an iterator object. (Though I doubt if this difference would be noticeable in most real-world scenarios.)

Answer (score 1):

How bout this:

```
public static List<T> ConvertToGenericList<T>(IList listOfObjects)
{
    List<T> items = new List<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        items.Add((T)listOfObjects[i]);
    }
     return items;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<object> listObject = new List<object>();
listObject.Add("ITEM 1");
listObject.Add("ITEM 2");
listObject.Add("ITEM 3");
List<string> listString = Converter.ConvertToGenericList<string>(listObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it one step.  Instead, try something like this:

```
        List<object> listObject = new List<object>();
        listObject.Add( "ITEM 1" );
        listObject.Add( "ITEM 2" );
        listObject.Add( "ITEM 3" );

        List<string> lstStr = new List<string>( listObject.Count );

        foreach ( object obj in listObject )
        {
            lstStr.Add( obj.ToString() );
        }
```

Comment: this is wrong, he doesn't want toc all ToString() on thos object, he wants to convert it to a string object. Technically your example will work this time, but only for strings. But if he happens to bump into a more advanced object, he wont be able to use this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> listString = (from o in listObject select (string)o).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

My first post... Hope usefull looks work in my project...

```
        public  dynamic ConvertList(Type CallingType)
    {

        dynamic DynamicList;

        if (CallingType == TypeOfValue)
        {
            Type d1 = typeof(List<>);

            Type[] typeArgs = { TypeOfValue };

            Type DynamicListType = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);


            object DynamicListObj = Activator.CreateInstance(DynamicListType);


            DynamicList = Convert.ChangeType(DynamicListObj, DynamicListType);


            foreach (object ValueElement in ValueRange)
            {
                    dynamic el = Convert.ChangeType(ValueElement, TypeOfValue);
                    DynamicList.Add(el);
            }

        }
        else //retrun empty List but with right type
        {
            Type d1 = typeof(List<>);

            Type[] typeArgs = { CallingType };

            Type DynamicListType = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

            object DynamicListObj = Activator.CreateInstance(DynamicListType);

            DynamicList = Convert.ChangeType(DynamicListObj, DynamicListType);
        }

        return DynamicList;
    }
```

I think that I'll add also a try catch somewhere.

how to test

```
                if (PropertyType == typeof(UInt32))
                {
                    List<UInt32> UInt32_test = NewProperty.ConvertList(PropertyType);
                }
                if (PropertyType == typeof(string))
                {

                    List<string> string_test = NewProperty.ConvertList(PropertyType);
                }
```